# Скрытый запуск консольного приложения

Tags: c++, windows, процесс, вывод

Есть Windows-программа типа сервера, сделана как консольная, но висит себе глубоко в фоне, никому не видна и не слышна (например, `editbin /subsystem:windows`).

Есть вторая консольная программа, которая не хочет писать в файл, а только в поток вывода, добраться до ее исходников никак не возможно. Хочтся в первой программе получить ее вывод. Писала бы она в файл - все было бы замечательно, сделать ее не консольной (тот же `editbin`), и запуск ее никак не проявлялся бы.

Если запускать ее с перенаправлением `prog > file` - все равно открывается окно. Если пробовать через что-то вроде `start /min` - сначала окно `cmd.exe` открывается, потом оно закрывается, и остается фоновое окно, которое хоть и не портит жэкран, но в полосе задач висит. Это еще бы можно было терпеть, но вот "вспышка" черного окна на весь экран портит всю эстетичность ))) Пробовал `_popen`, еще хуже.

Как-то можно это обойти? Из скрытой программы вызвать консольную с перенаправлением вывода, чтоб она на экране вообще не была видна ни на мгновение?

Вызывающая программа написана на С++, но это вряд ли важно?

Comment: *"Если запускать ее с перенаправлением prog > file - все равно открывается окно"* А запускаете как, `std::system`? Может попробовать библиотекой а-ля https://github.com/DaanDeMeyer/reproc ?

Comment: [первая ссылка из гугла](https://helgeklein.com/blog/how-to-run-console-programs-without-a-console-window/) — запуск через `CreateProcess()` с `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` не работает?

Comment: Ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43582022/boostprocess-hide-console-on-windows/43583001

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Я пробовал `spawnl`. С библиотеками может быть проблема, потому что приложение старое, на Open Watcom, со своими библиотеками. Я посмотрю, спасибо.\

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы получить вывод программы ее поток вывода следует перенаправить. Чтобы не показывалось окно следует при создании процесса в структуре `STARTUPINFO` передавать флаг `SW_HIDE`. Ну а еще можно использовать boost.process, реализующий обертки для этого всего:

```
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/process.hpp>
#include <boost/process/io.hpp>
#include <boost/process/windows.hpp>

#include <sstream>

#include <Windows.h>

int WINAPI
wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    namespace bp = ::boost::process;

    bp::opstream in{};
    bp::ipstream out{};
    bp::child process{"curl --version", (bp::std_out > out), (bp::std_in < in), bp::windows::hide};
    ::std::stringstream report{};
    report << "spawned child process" << ::std::endl;
    in.close();
    ::boost::array<char, 256> buf{};
    ::std::streamsize total_read_bytes_count{};
    for (;;)
    {
        out.read(buf.data(), buf.size());
        ::std::streamsize const read_bytes_count{out.gcount()};
        if (read_bytes_count)
        {
            report.write(buf.data(), read_bytes_count);
            total_read_bytes_count += read_bytes_count;
        }
        if (not out)
        {
            report << "\ndone reading " << total_read_bytes_count << ::std::endl;
            break;
        }
        continue;
    }
    process.join();
    report << "done with child process" << ::std::endl;
    ::MessageBoxA(HWND{}, report.str().c_str(), "Report", MB_OK);
    return 0;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: С Boost может быть проблема, потому что приложение старое, на еще Open Watcom, со своими библиотеками. Стандатрными средствами + Windows API как-то можно обойтись?

Comment: Что значит "может быть проблема"? boost использует тот же самый winapi, как описано в начале ответа.

Comment: Потому что он требует `libboost_что_то_там`, а скомпилировать boost под Open Watcom не получалось даже когда OW был популярен. Как этого же можно добиться без Boost? Перенаправление требует участия `cmd.exe`? Т.е. `CreateProcess` надо делать для `cmd.exe`?

Comment: Перенаправление не требует участие cmd.exe, все делается через CreateProcess.

Comment: Подскажите, что передавать в `CreateProcess`, чтоб сработало перенаправление? Я пробовал разные верианты, у меня ничего не получается..

Comment: ¿Почему бы не попробовать [вариант из официальной документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/creating-a-child-process-with-redirected-input-and-output)?

Comment: Спасибо, попробую...

Comment: Да, это решило проблему. Пришлось только консольную программу сделать windows-программой с помощью editbin (иначе открывалась полноценная консоль...). Ну, и мгновенное какое-то мерцание в момент запуска осталось, но это уже ерунда.

Comment: Нее, никакого мерцания при запуске быть не должно и консоль не должна открываться.

Comment: Вызываемое приложение консольное. Если оставить его таковым, консоль открывается явно. Если обработать `editbin /subsystem:windows application.exe`  - то какая-то, что называется, микросекундная "вспышка", как будто только рамку от консоли нарисовало и тут же стерло. Вот мой код: https://pastebin.com/uHMcUuQQ Мое приложение - 32 разряда, написано на OpenWatcom, серверное (сделано как консольное, но с указанием сделать windows (линковщиику передается `system    nt_win`), общение через иконку в области уведомлений), вызываемое приложение - 64-разрядное, операционка Windows 10. Где мой прокол?..

Comment: Прокол в отсутствии вышеупомянутого флага SW_HIDE

Comment: Спасибо, попробую. Правда, уже завтра...