# Как узнать размер Большой строки. С++

Tags: c++

Есть код.

```
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <iostream>

int main(void) {
    std::string X;
    X=system("curl https://education.yandex.ru/handbook/cpp");
    std::cout<<X;
    std::cout<<"\n\n\n"<<"**" <<"\nSize"<<X.size();
    
}
```

Вывод в командной строке такой

```
**
Size1
```

Как вывести размер данной строки?

Comment: Вас совсем не смущает, что [`system`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system) возвращает целое число, а не строку?...

Comment: NSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE - вот тип. Это не целое число.

Comment: Не понимаю в чем проблема. После вызова system, на экране появляется не целое значение а много символов т.е. сайт который я спасил. Как записать эти значения в переменную.

Comment: команда "curl .." записывает результат в поток консоли и вы это видите. в вашу программу возвращается только целое число как код успешности. можно попробовать перенаправить строку во временный файл: "curl https : //education.yandex.ru/handbook/cpp > tmp" и потом этот файл считать..

Comment: Тип ЧЕГО? Строки X? И какое это имеет отношение к тому, что возвращает `system`? По сути вы написали (если `system` завершился успешно) `string X = int(0);` (кстати, попробуйте :)). К выводу программой `curl` результат не имеет никакого отношения. По-хорошему, можно использовать `popen` или вывод в файл, но уж никак не присваивание строке целочисленного значения :)

Comment: Считывание вывода процесса: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1367886/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/1368083#1368083

Answer (score 2):

Медленно и по порядку.

Функция `system`, описанная, напримр, [здесь](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system), возвращает целочисленное значение типа `int`, при успешном выполнении равное 0.

Далее этот нуль присваивается строке `X`, которая с помощью оператора [`operator=(char)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%3D) присваивает этот нулевой символ вашей строке. Вы получаете строку с одним нулевым символом. Который при выводе в `cout` на консоли не виден, а размер строки из одного символа, как ни удивительно, равен именно 1, что и выводит ваша программа.

Так что вы *уже* вывели размер вашей строки `X` — которая не имеет никакого отношения к тому, что выводит `curl`.